# How does one integrate PayPal with a MERN stack

Tags: paypal, mern

Hey I would love to learn an know how payment gateways are implemented I have been google searching for code examples to implementing PayPal to a MERN Ecom project but I really could not find any examples on this

Can you please refer me to link where I check that up and if possible please you can make just a basic snippet on how this can be implemented I would really appreciate it

**This is the kind of implementation I would love to have**

1. Take in the customers Personal info i.e Name, Email and all necessary info etc
2. I would love to collect a shipping address

Comment: -ERN is just node.js with the react and express framework, so any JavaScript example will do. There are many JavaScript and node.js samples, including in the official PayPal documentation at https://developer.paypal.com , or the Checkout-NodeJS-SDK. What have you tried so far?

Comment: So you saying the same approach that I use in my client side is the same that I would in the back-end?

Because what I want to achieve in the font-end is having the PayPal button that will then give out the form and then send the data inserted there to the back-end to process and all.

Or may be I juts got confused because I was watching another YouTube video so this guy was having redirects based on the users interaction i.e if payment was success or canceled but note he was doing all this only with nodejs and using ejs so how can I implement that using react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what about approaches to implementing a server and client side confuses, but below is some documentation to review. The samples are in standard node.js and JavaScript, so no express or react details are considered. Make your own adjustments to use with express and react.

On the server, two new routes, one for "Set Up Transaction" and one for "Capture Transaction", documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

A client-side approval flow to connect to the above, documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

---

By default PayPal collects and returns a shipping address, so it will be available to you inside onApprove on the client side, or via an additional API call you could implement to get the details before going ahead with a capture, or simply in the final response of your order capture API call

When you capture an order, there will be a payment object with an ID. That is the PayPal transaction, and what you should persist in a database, and also what would be referenced for any refund.  (The order ID used during approval and any debug_id of the response can be kept around for logging purposes, but have no accounting or reporting value)